# Debug Acceleo mtl transformation

Tags: debugging, emf, acceleo

I have eclipse neon with Acceleo 3.7 and writing a simple example (the same as the one in [Getting Started](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started)) but I cannot debug the transformation using the 'Acceleo Plug-in Application' configuration. Actually, when I select this configuration, I cannot run the transformation at all and I get the following error:

`Couldn't load class org.eclipse.acceleo.module.umlsample.main.Generate from project org.eclipse.acceleo.module.umlsample`

When I run/debug the transformation with the 'Java Application' as the runner configuration, then the transformation runs however still not possible to debug the transformation.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse Mars and onward, the "plug-in application" launch is no longer functional because of API changes in the internal platform. It has been removed from the latest versions of Acceleo.

You will have to go the long way 'round to debug your generation: generate a [UI launcher](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started#Creating_a_UI_launcher), start a new eclipse runtime from your current eclipse ("Run > Run configurations", double click "eclipse application" and launch that), and you will have a new action to start your generation on models from that new runtime's workspace (as shown on the wiki's last image). This is debuggable from your first eclipse.